# How can I change price currency in woocommerce product snippets?

Tags: woocommerce, seo, google-search

I use RankMath plugin and changed product price currency in it's setting to IRR (Iranian Rial), and test product snippets in google search console it returns correct currency. Also the source code show IRR. But in real search in Google, the currency is $CAD (Canadian Dollar) in all products result search. How can I solve this problem where should I change the currency?